# Error building package regex-posix-0.96.0.0 with Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to compile a new Haskell project with Stack, but I'm getting this error message:

```
$ stack build
WARNING: Ignoring regex-posix's bounds on base (<0 && >=4.3 && <4.16); using base-4.14.1.0.
Reason: trusting snapshot over cabal file dependency information.
regex-posix                 > configure
regex-posix                 > Configuring regex-posix-0.96.0.0...
regex-posix                 > build
regex-posix                 > Preprocessing library for regex-posix-0.96.0.0..
regex-posix                 > compiling .stack-work\dist\274b403a\build\Text\Regex\Posix\Wrap_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
regex-posix                 > rsp file was: ".stack-work\\dist\\274b403a\\build\\Text\\Regex\\Posix\\hsc5BFC.rsp"
regex-posix                 > command was: C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.4\lib\../mingw/bin\gcc.exe -c .stack-work\dist\274b403a\build\Text\Regex\Posix\Wrap_hsc_make.c -o .stack-work\dist\274b403a\build\Text\Regex\Posix\Wrap_hsc_make.o -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=810 -Dmingw32_BUILD_OS=1 -Dx86_64_BUILD_ARCH=1 -Dmingw32_HOST_OS=1 -Dx86_64_HOST_ARCH=1 -Icbits -IC:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\include -I.stack-work\dist\274b403a\build\cbits -IC:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\include -I.stack-work\dist\274b403a\build\autogen -I.stack-work\dist\274b403a\build\global-autogen -include .stack-work\dist\274b403a\build\autogen\cabal_macros.h -IC:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20180531\mingw64\include -IC:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.4\lib\bytestring-0.10.12.0\include -IC:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.4\lib\base-4.14.1.0\include -IC:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.4\lib\integer-gmp-1.0.3.0\include -IC:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.4\lib/include -IC:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.4/lib/include/
regex-posix                 > error: Wrap.hsc:96:10: fatal error: regex.h: No such file or directory
regex-posix                 > compilation terminated.
regex-posix                 >
Progress 1/2

--  While building package regex-posix-0.96.0.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.4.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\274b403a build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I don't understand the initial warning. When looking at the [regex-posix package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix-0.96.0.0)'s dependencies, it does list `base (>=4.3 && <4.16)` as a dependency, but where does the `<0` come from?

I've set the resolver to LTS 18.0 in `stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-18.0
```

According to the [documentation of LTS 18.0](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.0), it uses `base-4.14.1.0`. If the versioning is lexicographic, I'd think that 4.14.1.0 fits the range that *regex-posix* requires (if we, for a moment, ignore the strange `<0` constraint).

Here are the relevant parts of my `package.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- regex-posix >= 0.96

library:
  source-dirs: src
  ghc-options:
  - -Wall
```

My `stack` version:

```
$ stack --version
Version 2.7.1, Git revision 8afe0c2932716b0441cf4440d6942c59568b6b19 x86_64 hpack-0.34.4
```

I'm on Windows 10.

FWIW, it's not that I care much about *regex-posix* in itself. In reality, I'm trying to set up a test project, and [test-framework](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework) depends on *regex-posix*.

How can I resolve this issue so that I can compile my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not about the version, that is just a warning. The real error is about a missing "regex.h" header for the underlying C library. That header is almost always present on posix platforms (like linux), but not on Windows. See https://github.com/haskell-hvr/regex-posix/issues/4

Particularly [this comment](https://github.com/haskell-hvr/regex-posix/issues/4#issuecomment-610952562) by Paul Johnson:

> Correction to the above: you don't need mingw64. You just need to install with the _regex-posix-clib flag enabled (note the underscore).
>
> With plain cabal: cabal install regex-posix -f _regex-posix-clib
>
> In Stack, add the following to your stack.yaml:
>
> ```
> extra-deps:
>    - regex-posix-clib-2.7
>
> flags:
>    regex-posix:
>       _regex-posix-clib: true
> ```

In that thread there is also a comment about the `<0` version: https://github.com/haskell-hvr/regex-posix/issues/4#issuecomment-699786233